# How to turn list into nested in a specific way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have a list: `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]`. I want to make it nested and put in sublists of two consecutive values ​​from the given list. if there are no two values ​​left, then one value should go to the sublist. so desired result is:  `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g"]]`.

I tried this:

```
original_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
nested_list = []

for i in range(0, len(original_list), 2):
    sublist = original_list[i:i+2]
    nested_list.append(sublist)

if len(original_list) % 2 != 0:
    nested_list[-2].append(nested_list[-1][0])
    nested_list.pop()

print(nested_list)
```

and the output was correct: `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]`.

But for this example:

```
original_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
nested_list = []

for i in range(0, len(original_list), 2):
    sublist = original_list[i:i+2]
    nested_list.append(sublist)

if len(original_list) % 2 != 0:
    nested_list[-2].append(nested_list[-1][0])
    nested_list.pop()

print(nested_list)
```

the output is `[['a', 'b', 'c']]` instead of `[['a', 'b'], ['c']]`

How could i fix it?

Comment: The output in your first example isn't correct either, since the `'g'` ends up in the same list as `e` and `f` rather than in its own list as in the initial problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zip` / `zip_longest` approaches suggested by [Samwise](/a/75617607/843953) and [Jorge](/a/75617798/843953) are good, but you could also do this by simply iterating over `original_list` and handling each element as you encounter it.
First, initialize `nested_list` as a list containing an empty list.

```
nested_list = [[]]
```

As you iterate over `original_list`, check that the last element of `nested_list` contains less than two elements. If it doesn't, append a new empty list to `nested_list`. If it does contain less than two elements (if it didn't earlier, this is now true since you appended an empty list), append the current element to that list:

```
for item in original_list:
    if len(nested_list[-1]) >= 2:
        nested_list.append([])

    nested_list[-1].append(item)
```

Now, `nested_list` looks like the desired output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to write clearly how to use `zip_longest` as [Samwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75617607/843953) suggested:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


combined = zip_longest(original_list[::2], original_list[1::2])
# Avoid None elements in the last list
nested_list= [[element for element in pair if element]
              for pair in combined]
```

This method can be easily generalized as `zip_longest` can get as many arguments as you would like to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete this part:

```
if len(original_list) % 2 != 0:
    nested_list[-2].append(nested_list[-1][0])
    nested_list.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the way there by using `zip` to pair every even element with a corresponding odd element (this is roughly the same as what the first half of your code does):

```
>>> original_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
>>> [list(pair) for pair in zip(original_list[::2], original_list[1::2])]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

and then handle the last element (if the length of the overall list is odd) as a special case:

```
>>> nested_list = [list(pair) for pair in zip(original_list[::2], original_list[1::2])]
>>> if len(original_list) % 2:
...     nested_list.append([original_list[-1]])
...
>>> nested_list
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
```

It's also possible to construct the `zip` in such a way as to handle the odd case on its own (i.e. adding a dummy element to the end, or using `zip_longest`, and then accounting for that when building the list of pairs) but I think the above way is the simplest.

Comment: Can you tell what's wrong with their first half? Doesn't it do the job already? I don't get it. Why did you do this zip stuff?